# Showing variable on click with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am trying to show a variable called "damage" as HTML once an image is clicked.
By using this function

```
    function click() {
        document.getElementById("clicked").innerHTML = damage


    }
```

I've posted it into this JSfiddle with all the required Javascript and html.

http://jsfiddle.net/xvzj0d9p/

Comment: Do you declare `donuts` and `count` variables? If so, where? Also where is your `damageCount` element and you haven't got anything in your `click()` function to trigger `addDonut2()` *Please update your question displaying all relevant source code*

Comment: Please add complete code snippet

Comment: Do you see errors in the console?

Comment: @NewToJS I've added the whole code now.

Comment: @FrederikLund - Please add your html too

Comment: @FrederikLund We only need the relevant source code, please take your time to plan your question. I'm sure if you take the time to plan your question others will help you. I can't see many people fishing through a game source code for a minor error. If you want to share the full source code please include the html so we can run the game and find the error that way. Thank you.

Comment: @NewToJS Yeah i realised that before you commented. so i was already working on fixing it. It should be fixed now. Sorry!

Comment: @FrederikLund I see you're having problems formatting the source code into your question. You can create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ and share the link in your question. If you create a jsfiddle please try replicate the issue.

Comment: whare are the count and damage elements ?

Comment: @NewToJS Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/xvzj0d9p/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the addDonut2 function in your click function

```
    function addDonut2()
   {
    donuts = donuts + fire;
    count.innerHTML = donuts;
    damage = damage + fire;
    document.getElementById("damageCount").innerHTML = damage;
   }


 //Here the  Damage is being defined. It is the damage i want to display. 


    function click() {
        addDonut2();
        document.getElementById("clicked").innerHTML = damage


    }
```

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot to add the part to the snippet. I've added the full code now.

Comment: No. When i click the image calling the "click" function nothing happens. I've tried to edit the code to what you've shown.

Comment: I think its a formatting error. I've made a new function with your exact code - And it is working now! Thanks for your help.